# Can't instantiate class ...; no empty constructor

Tags: java, android, android-view

When I run my `PaintView.java`, I receive the following error in logcat, namely can't instantiate class `com.example.connectthedots.PaintView`; no empty constructor.

```
07-22 18:47:43.453: D/dalvikvm(19728): newInstance failed: no <init>()
07-22 18:47:43.453: D/AndroidRuntime(19728): Shutting down VM
07-22 18:47:43.453: W/dalvikvm(19728): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bf6da0)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728): Process: com.example.connectthedots, PID: 19728
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.connectthedots/com.example.connectthedots.PaintView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.connectthedots.PaintView; no empty constructor
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.connectthedots.PaintView; no empty constructor
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
07-22 18:47:43.453: E/AndroidRuntime(19728):    ... 11 more
```

My PaintView.java looks like this:

```
package com.example.connectthedots;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class PaintView extends View { 

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP = 24;
private static final int BACKGROUND = 0xFFDDDDDD;
private List<Point> mPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
private int mLastPointIndex = 0;
private int mTouchTolerance;
private boolean isPathStarted = false;

public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);

    // TODO just test points
    Point p1 = new Point(20, 20);
    Point p2 = new Point(100, 100);
    Point p3 = new Point(200, 250);
    Point p4 = new Point(280, 400);
    Point p5 = new Point(350, 600);
    Point p6 = new Point(400, 500);
    mPoints.add(p1);
    mPoints.add(p2);
    mPoints.add(p3);
    mPoints.add(p4);
    mPoints.add(p5);
    mPoints.add(p6);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);

    // TODO just test points
    Point p1 = new Point(20, 20);
    Point p2 = new Point(100, 100);
    Point p3 = new Point(200, 250);
    Point p4 = new Point(280, 400);
    Point p5 = new Point(350, 600);
    Point p6 = new Point(400, 500);
    mPoints.add(p1);
    mPoints.add(p2);
    mPoints.add(p3);
    mPoints.add(p4);
    mPoints.add(p5);
    mPoints.add(p6);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);
    clear();

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(BACKGROUND);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    // TODO remove if you dont want points to be drawn
    for (Point point : mPoints) {
        canvas.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, mPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

    if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex)) {
        mPath.reset();
        // user starts from given point so path can beis started
        isPathStarted = true;
    } else {
        // user starts move from point which doen's belongs to mPinst list
        isPathStarted = false;
    }

}

//ADDED WITH LAST EDIT
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    // draw line with finger move
    if (isPathStarted) {
        mPath.reset();
        Point p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        mPath.lineTo(x, y);
    }
}

/**
 * Draws line.
 */
private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex + 1) && isPathStarted) {
        // move finished at valid point so draw whole line

        // start point
        Point p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        // end point
        p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex + 1);
        mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
        // increment point index
        ++mLastPointIndex;
        isPathStarted = false;
    }

}

/**
 * Sets paint
 * 
 * @param paint
 */
public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
    this.mPaint = paint;
}

/**
 * Returns image as bitmap
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return mBitmap;
}

/**
 * Clears canvas
 */
public void clear() {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(BACKGROUND);
    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Checks if user touch point with some tolerance
 */
private boolean checkPoint(float x, float y, int pointIndex) {
    if (pointIndex == mPoints.size()) {
        // out of bounds
        return false;
    }
    Point point = mPoints.get(pointIndex);
    //EDIT changed point.y to poin.x in the first if statement
    if (x > (point.x - mTouchTolerance) && x < (point.x + mTouchTolerance)) {
        if (y > (point.y - mTouchTolerance) && y < (point.y + mTouchTolerance)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public List<Point> getPoints() {
    return mPoints;
}

public void setPoints(List<Point> points) {
    this.mPoints = points;
}

private int dp2px(int dp) {
    Resources r = getContext().getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return (int) px;
}
}
```

FYI: activity_paint_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PaintView" >

    <com.example.connectthedots.PaintView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What is the mistake here?

Comment: You didn't make an empty constructor?

Comment: I think this has more to do with the code you are using to instantiate the PaintView object rather than the PaintView implementation. I don't know why you would want to call an empty constructor for this object.

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.connectthedots.PaintView; no empty constructor

As the exception tells you, `PaintView` requires a constructor without any parameters :

```
public PaintView() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an empty Constructor:

```
    public PaintView() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think simply adding an empty constructor is the best solution here.  If you want to instantiate and use a `PaintView` object, you should to use one of the already defined constructors.  If you take a look at the [Android View Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), there is no empty constructor.  Since you have a subclass of `View`, it doesn't really make sense to implement an empty constructor.

Instead, I would recommend you take a look at the code you are using to create the `PaintView` object.  Right now, you probably have some thing like:

```
PaintView mPaintView = new PaintView();
```

Instead, you should use one of the already implemented constructors:

```
PaintView mPaintView = new PaintView(mContext);
```

Where `mContext` is a valid `Context` object in this instance.  If you are doing this in an `Activity`, you could just pass the current instance of that `Activity` to the constructor.

Comment: mPaint is inside my PaintView() activity. If I do what you describe I get errors. Could you point out how it should look exactly by looking at my code. I'm new to Android Development and got parts of the code from someone else.

Comment: Sure, just post the code you are using to create mPaint.  You might try **new PaintView(this);** too.

Comment: I create mPaint a couple of times,          `private Paint mPaint;`            `public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mPaint = new Paint();`                          `public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();`                          `public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    mPaint = new Paint();`

Comment: No, I need to see where you create your PaintView Object, sorry.  Just edit your question rather then trying to post it in a comment.  Easier to read.

Comment: Somewhere arround line 20 in the PaintView.java

Comment: That is where you *declare* your PaintView class. Is there a different file where you use it?

Comment: No, if you want I can zip the whole project up and upload it somewhere