# android - onDraw() Method

Tags: java, android, graphics

I'm trying to draw a rectangle, but I'll get an error if I run it. The LogFile says: can't instanciate class [...] no empty constructor. but why?

```
public class MainActivity extends View {

public MainActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect ourRect = new Rect();
    ourRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);

    Paint blue = new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't instantiate class ...; no empty constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893608/cant-instantiate-class-no-empty-constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement default empty constructor for your class

```
public MainActivity() {
}
```

Comment: So instead of public MainActivity(Context context)...?