# Can't instantiate class …; no empty constructor

Tags: android

I have this famous error [Can't instantiate class ...; no empty constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893608/cant-instantiate-class-no-empty-constructor) even after i added an empty constructor it's doesn't solve the problem. here's the code:

```
public class BackService extends Service {
    private BackService() { }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    SmsListener SmsListener = new SmsListener();
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        registerReceiver(SmsListener, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

and in manifest :

```
   <service android:name="MainActivity$BackService" />
```

How i can solve it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make the constructor `public` or eliminate that zero-argument constructor. Having a `private` zero-argument constructor will not work, as the framework cannot use it.

Also, this needs to be a `static` class, since from your `<service>` element, it appears to be inside `MainActivity` (which is very strange).

Comment: @Nizar: "I can't make it static as i have non-static codes with it" -- you do not have a choice. Besides, the point behind having a service is to be able to do work when your activity is gone. Perhaps the solution is to not use a service in the first place.

Comment: is there a way to register it programmatically? like receivers?

Comment: @Nizar: No, sorry.

Comment: @Shadow: That registers a receiver in the manifest. It does not register a service dynamically. Depending on the use case would determine if registering the `SMS_RECEIVED` receiver in the manifest is the proper course of action.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right that solution does not register a service dynamically that always has a receiver on it but could mimics the effect though the receiver is always register in manifest. another solution may be to register the receiver itself dynamically (in a service or activity)

Comment: add this to manifest application tag: `<receiver android:name=".SmsListener" > <intent-filter android:priority="500"> <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> </intent-filter> </receiver>` then when you need to react to new sms just do what you need when you do not want to react then do noting. you can change a shared preference or a static value to know you should react to new sms or not

Answer (score 0):

The empty constructor needs to be accessible. You could define it as `public`:

```
public BackService() { }
```

Or just remove it altogether and use the default constructor (since the class has no other constructors).

Comment: i did both, private and public

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to be notified about new SMS *only when* your activity is visible to user do these:**

remove service entirely

move this line to Activity's `onCreate`

```
SmsListener SmsListener = new SmsListener();
```

move this line to Activity's `onResume`

```
registerReceiver(SmsListener, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

add this line to Activity's `onPause`

```
unregisterReceiver(SmsListener);
```

---

**Otherwise if you want to *always* be notified about new SMS just add a broadcast receiver to your project:**

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListener" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="500">
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** construct `Service` (or `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`) explicitly. The `Android` system does that for you internally. The proper way to start a service is via `startService()` with an `Intent`, not by calling something like `new YourService()`.

In your case, just delete this line:

```
private BackService() { }
```

..and make sure you're starting the `Service` correctly.

Comment: I cannot provide you with an example here, yet I recommend you to google for **android components** and read about their fundamentals _(spoiler: there are 4 of them)_. Also, for this particular case I suggest you follow this tutorial on `Services`: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html